# MAPI error MAPI_E_STORE_FULL

Tags: python, python-2.7, ole, mapi

I get the `MAPI_E_STORE_FULL` OLE Error when I am trying to open a message item from store(mapistore.OpenEntry).

On going through some google search pages I found that this OLE error may be a result of using old style pst files(pre 2003 versions) if it has reached the size of 2 GB.

But again I am just trying to open the message item and not writing anything into the store. I am using MAPI interface through Python to read the contents of a message store. I am really confused. Is this error expected in case of reading the pst??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You PST file is almost 2GB bit and you're using the old PST file format. That supports max. 2GB per file. Microsoft explains [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-and-use-pst-data-files-in-different-versions-of-outlook-HP001231987.aspx) how to convert it into the new format.

Use `MFCMapi` utility to open the store. You can isolate the problem with help of this tool.[MFCmapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/)

**Edited:** [Same problem as you have](http://forum.groovypost.com/microsoft-office/how-to-convert-old-pst-ansi-to-new-unicode-pst-format-t95921.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tool. I am trying my hands on it. Your 1st point....I have already mentioned that I am reading the store not writing anything to it. Would it still be a problem for the old style pst? How do we know if a pst is pre 2003 or post 2003?

Comment: If my answer is the solution. Please upvote and accept.